# Decoding a multidimensional Json array and seperate it into 3 different arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am receiving the json payload below from a webservice and I am trying to separate it into 3 different arrays using loops after decoding whlist keeping the same array keys:

```
{
"id": 5705376,
"title": "Satellite Installation",
"created_at": "2017-09-07T14:02:19.000Z",
"updated_at": "2017-09-07T14:02:19.000Z",
"customer_id": 3126803,
"way_points": [{
    "id": 7405587,
    "lat": -26.0578251,
    "lng": 28.02189520000002,
    "task_id": 5705376,
    "done": false,
    "allow_editing_inventory": true,
    "customer_contact_ids": [3126803],
    "customer": {
        "original_phone_number": null,
        "last_open_at": null,
        "last_order_at": null,
        "uploaded_profile_image": {
            "url": "/images/avatar.png"
        },
        "original_lat": null,
        "original_lng": null,
        "district": null,
        "house_number": null,
        "street": null
    },
    "full_address": "8 Anslow Ln, Bryanston, Sandton, 2191, South Africa"
}],
"customer": {
    "id": 3126803,
    "name": "Lance",
    "address": "8 Anslow Ln, Bryanston, Sandton, 2191, South Africa",
    "lat": -26.0578251,
    "lng": 28.0218952,
    "created_at": "2017-08-29T10:00:32.360Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-09-07T14:02:19.860Z",
    "phone": null,
    "merchant_id": 11221,
    "allow_login": false,
    "stripe_id": null,
    "original_phone_number": null,
    "last_open_at": null,
    "last_order_at": null,
    "uploaded_profile_image": {
        "url": "/images/avatar.png"
    },
    "original_lat": null,
    "original_lng": null,
    "house_number": null,
    "street": null
},
"late": false,
"external_id": "5705376",
"uuid": "28095e33-b30c-4e35-98d2-aae6ad428f66",
"dispatcher_id": null,
"team_ids": [12422],
"ready_to_execute": true,
"tip_driver_enabled": false,
"automatically_assigned": false,
"task_inventories": null,
"task_notes": null
}
```

For the values in the "way_points" key i want to come up with one array called waypoint after decoding whilst ignoring the customers array in it. I also want to change the "id" key name to "waypoint_id" in the process.

For the values in the "customers" key (in the main array) I want to come up with one array called "waypoint" after decoding whilst assigning the value of the "url" 
 key to the "uploaded profile image" key. I also want to change the "id" key name to "customer_id" in the process.

Any element that is outside of the arrays mentioned above (thus elements in the main array that are not assigned to arrays), I want them to form an array called "orders".

How can i go about doing this. I am new at LOOPS

Comment: Why would you need different variables? Just decode the json using `json_decode()` and you have everything that you need.

Comment: What you've shared is not valid JSON are you sure that's the right one?

Comment: I am sorry about the invalid json, i edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to decode the json encoded string into a usable format, either `array` or an object. You can find all possible options for `json_decode` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$inputArray = json_decode($inputString, true);
```

Now for the loop. To keep it simple, you can initialize the three arrays you need firsthand as empty arrays. Then, in the loop, simply check for the key value and choose what array to append the data to.

```
$waypoints = array();
$customers = array();
$orders = array();

$count = 0;
foreach($inputArray as $key => $element) {
    /* using if statements */
    if($key === 'way_points') {
        $waypoints[] = $element;
    }
    elseif($key === 'customer') {
        $customers[] = $element;
    }
    else {
        $orders[$count][$key] = $element;
    }

    /* using a switch/case */
    switch($key) {
        case 'way_points':
            $waypoints[] = $element;
            break;
        case 'customer':
            $customers[] = $element;
            break;
        default:
            $orders[$count][$key] = $element;
            break;
    }

    $count++;
}
```

At this point you should have all the data you need, but we still haven't changed the keys. You could leave it as-is, after all it is pretty self-explanatory that the `id` key in `$waypoints` reprensents the `waypoint_id`. However, if you do absolutely need to change the key, there's a few ways to do this. You can loop over the newly formed `$waypoints` array and modify the keys in this new loop.

```
$waypoints = change_keys($waypoints);

function change_keys($arr) {
    return array_map(function($waypoint) {
        return array(
            'waypoint_id' => $waypoint['id'],
            'lat' => $element['lat'],
            /* remaining fields */
        );
    }, $arr);
}
```

Or you can cut the amount of steps and do it in the initial `foreach` loop

```
$waypoints = array();
$customers = array();
$orders = array();

$count = 0;
foreach($inputArray as $key => $element) {
    if($key === 'way_points') {
        $waypoints[] = array_map(function($element) {
            return array(
                'waypoint_id' => $element['id'],
                'lat' => $element['lat'],
                /* remaining fields */
            );
        }, $arr);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

You can find more info on `array_map` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

---

As an aside, as @jeroen mentionned in the comments, you can simply use `json_decode` and you'll be left with a usable associative array. to loop over the waypoints for example, you would simply write `foreach($myArray[waypoints] as $key => $waypoint)`.